# Access App Global variables in Xamarin Prism.Forms Module (Prism.Modularity)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, prism-6

I am developing Xamarin Forms cross platform Application with Prism.Forms.
Trying to implement modularity in my app using Prism.Modularity.
I have created couple of modules (xamarin forms portable class libraries) in addition to the existing default portable class library. Now I have to use the global static variables that i have declared in App.Xaml.cs (In APP class) in the module. Is there anyway i can access current App in module? Or is there any alternative to share data between modules and the main App.

Answer (score 0):

Like shared services?

Declare an interface somewhere reachable by all modules that need it, and register an implementation singleton in one of the modules...

Example:

```
public interface ISomeDataProvider
{
    int SomeNumber { get; set; }
}

internal class SimpleDataProvider : ISomeDataProvider
{
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; }
}

internal class InAModule
{
    public InAModule( ISomeDataProvider dataProvider )
    {
        dataProvider.SomeNumber = 1;
    }
}

internal class InAnotherModule
{
    public InAnotherModule( ISomeDataProvider dataProvider )
    {
        _dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    public void PrintSomeNumber()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( _dataProvider.SomeNumber.ToString() );
    }

    private readonly ISomeDataProvider _dataProvider;
}
```